# Hair curves flipped inside after a bit aditional sculpting

Tags: modifiers, particles, normals, hair, interpolation

Hair curves flipped inside the normals surface.
The UV unwrap does not help.
What the reason it can be ?
When I try to redone an interpolation modifier the result is same.

[image]